# kafka connect convertor vs transforms

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to create following workflow

1. nginx logs are picked up by kafka connector and uploaded to a topic
2. An hdfs sync connector then puts these logs into hdfs
3. Hive is used over the hdfs data to analyze (e.g. number of accesses group by IP address etc)

While I can arrange the nginx logs in the format that would be required by the hive metastore (space or comma separated required fields only), I was wondering if this could be done without touching the nginx log format by

1. using converter similar to org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
2. using single message transforms

both of the approaches would require a custom implementation, and there is very little documentation about how one would go about doing the same.

Which one would be the right approach do achieve this? and are there any examples available for parsing nginx logs output/any source data while it is being written to a topic using kafka connect. I am using standalone file connector.

Answer (score 5):

Kafka Connect source connectors are responsibility for converting the messages from the representation in the source (e.g., nginx log message format) into an in-memory representation call `SourceRecord` that uses Kafka Connect's `Struct` and `Schema` data structures. Kafka Connect then uses it's *converters* to convert the in-memory representation of records into the `byte[]` representation that is actually written to Kafka.

This separation of responsibilities is very important, as it allows you to mix and match functionality. The exact nature of the serialized messages written to the topics can be changed independently of the connectors. For example, some developers prefer to write the data using JSON. Many other prefer to serialize the messages with Avro using a common Schema Registry, the combination of which can ensure all messages use a specific schema yet letting that schema evolve over time in backward compatible ways so that producers can evolve to a new version of the schema while consumers can adapt to that schema at some later point in time. Using Avro schemas and Schema Registries offer [tremendous benefits](https://www.confluent.io/blog/tag/schema-registry/).

Bottom line: don't create a custom *converter* that knows about the upstream data source. You're going to box yourself in with too much coupling, since the `byte[]` representation is going to be custom and only consumable by consumers and applications that also know this particular representation.

Instead, use an existing source connector and [Single Message Transforms](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect_transforms) if you need to slightly adjust the in-memory message structure. In this case, it might even be best to create a custom source connector (perhaps specializing an existing file-based source connector) that adapts the nginx log message format into the structured in-memory representation.